# How to use one template in multiple Ironrouter route?

Tags: templates, meteor, iron-router

I want to display the template named "home" with the route "/" and "/home" but with my code it doesn't work

```
/** Iron router config file **/
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  notFoundTemplate: '404',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  fastRender: true,
});

// Home
Router.route('/', {
  name: 'home',
  waitOn: function() {
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe('infosContainers'),
      Meteor.subscribe('infosMachines'),
      Meteor.subscribe('alertes'),
    ];
  },
  fastRender: true,
});

Router.route('/home', {
  name: 'home',
  waitOn: function() {
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe('infosContainers'),
      Meteor.subscribe('infosMachines'),
      Meteor.subscribe('alertes'),
    ];
  },
  fastRender: true,
});
```

It doesn't like the fact that the template "home" is in 2 routes (because if I set `name: sokasok` in the second one it works )

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'name' is not for the template render, it's the name of the route. What you need to do is call `this.render('home')` in `action` of the route.

```
Router.route('/home', {
  waitOn: function() {
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe('infosContainers'),
      Meteor.subscribe('infosMachines'),
      Meteor.subscribe('alertes'),
    ];
  },
  action: function(){
      this.render('home');
  }
  fastRender: true,
});
```